# Swift adding clickable tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

When I create a tableview, I cannot click on any of the items I put on the tableview. I was wondering how can I create a tableview that has every item clickable and when the user clicks on an item( say a city name, for example) it redirects the user to a different viewcontroller. ( for example if there are 22 clickable items in the tableview, there will be a total of 22 new different viewcontrollers )
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you implement the UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: You'll want to use the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. If you start a new xcode project using the Master Detail Template the boilerplate code does exactly this.

Comment: Here is demo project for tableview https://github.com/paresh1994/ProtocolDelegation-

Answer (score 0):

There are three major functions that a UITableViewDataSource must contain for the table view to work properly with user interaction (Pressing each row, for example). These functions are:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

The function you are looking to use is the third one. It is called when a user selects a certain row by tapping it on screen. You can find out the row index with 'indexPath'.

If you would like to go to 22 different view controllers, you need to create a manual segue between each one and label them accordingly. Then, you would want to call each individual segue depending on which row was selected inside of that third function! You can call a segue with an identifier with the performSegue() function.

Note that the class that contains these functions must be of type UITableViewDataSource, and you should tell the table view that it is the data source in the ViewDidLoad() function like so:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what a simple code can look like:

```
import UIKit
class viewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var identifiers = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // fill your identifiers here

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 22
    } 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier") as! yourCell
        // fill your cell's data in here
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        // here you can use someThing like an array of your segue identifiers
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: identifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)
        //Or you can just implement a switch with every case doing what you want that cell to do which i don't recommend if you have 22 rows 
    }
}
```